# Is not stencil independent between rendertextures in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two cameras for off-screen rendering on rendertexture which is generated dynamically. A cameraA(depth 1) render full resolution with stencil object to crop the region except the region inside a small window. Another cameraB(depth 0) render low resolution and use culling mask to avoid stencil object being rendered. The stencil objects are all layered. I suppose cameraB render first and it would not render the stencil object. But the result frame appears stencil cropped effect. So I am wondering what's wrong with it?

My Unity version is 2017.2.0f3, any idea or samples would be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: I think you will have more success in [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. I'll post it to there.